# How do I find a specific range in a file using python?

Tags: python, linux, unix

I am trying to find a specific range in a file that is equal to a specific MAC address.

Here is the code:

```
sensortag=0
while sensortag != "B4:99:4C:64:33:E0":
    os.system("hcitool lescan> scan.txt & pkill --signal SIGINT hcitool")
    scan = open("scan.txt", "r")
    readscan = scan.read()

    #read range 40-56 in file, NOTE: THIS WORKS IF I JUST KEEP IT if readscan[40] == "B", b being the start of the MAC address
    if readscan[40:56] == "B4:99:4C:64:33:E0":
        print "SensorTag found."
        sensortag = "B4:99:4C:64:33:E0"
```

The code just infinitely loops.

**UPDATE: Thanks to jkalden my code now works with this workaround:**

```
if "B4:99:4C:64:33:E0" in readscan:
        print "SensorTag found."
        sensortag = "B4:99:4C:64:33:E0"
```

I use a for loop to print the index numbers and the corresponding value to verify that it is the 40-56 range I need.

```
for index, i in enumerate(readscan):
    print index, i
```

Comment: I don't see a question here

Comment: I have updated the title: How do I find a specific range in a file using python?

Comment: I'm unsure whether I got you right, but how about `if "B4:99:4C:64:33:E0" in readscan: print "SensorTag found." sensortag = "B4:99:4C:64:33:E0" `?

Comment: Perfect! if "B4:99:4C:64:33:E0" in readscan: print "SensorTag found." sensortag = "B4:99:4C:64:33:E0" WORKS! Thank you jkalden!

Comment: @JonathanDavies check the code

Comment: @Hackaholic, thanks for the solution, this would also work. However, I think the one jkalden provided is sufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jkalden my code now works with this workaround:

```
if "B4:99:4C:64:33:E0" in readscan:
        print "SensorTag found."
        sensortag = "B4:99:4C:64:33:E0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're while loop does not end. Try something like this

```
os.system("hcitool lescan> scan.txt & pkill --signal SIGINT hcitool")
found = False
with open('scan.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if line[40:56] == 'B4:99:4C:64:33:E0':
            found = True
            break

if found:
    print "SensorTag found."
```

Comment: This has not worked. The while loop does end if it is: if readscan[40] == "B". A single value to find instead of a range [40:56]

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
os.system("hcitool lescan> scan.txt & pkill --signal SIGINT hcitool")
scan = open("scan.txt", "r")
readscan = scan.read()

all_Mac = re.findall("([0-9A-F]{2}(?::[0-9A-F]{2}){5})",readscan)
if 'B4:99:4C:64:33:E0' in all_Mac:
    print "Sensor tag found"
```

i used regexto find all macaddress